# using one class instead of several

Tags: css

I use very often combination of several classes:

```
<a href="something" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg mt20">something</a>
```

If there is a way I can simplify? for instance

```
<a href="something" class="btn-my">something</a>
```

where .btn-my would be a combination of .btn .btn-default .btn-block .btn-lg .mt20
How would I do it in css file? Is there something more simpler like

```
.btn-my{.btn .btn-default .btn-block .btn-lg .mt20}
```

Comment: You would just take all the CSS rules from those classes and combine them into one new class.

Comment: The reason why often multiple classes are used is because that way those classes can be combined as desired for different objects. That allows to implement more compact styling rules in the end, since you do not have to double general themes.

Comment: Why do you want to simplify something which is doing exactly what it says, and can be interpreted easily by someone looking at the code, not to mention, as arkascha said, allowing you to combine them in any way you please.

Comment: The only suggestion that I'd make is to use a CSS preprocessor like SASS and a method like [**`@extend`**](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7).

Answer (score 0):

Ex:

```
// spread out css
.class1 {
  background: blue;
}

.class2 {
  color: white;
}

// consolidated css
.myConsolidatedClass {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

As far as combining classes, css by default doesn't support that. I would look into using `scss` and you can use modules /w `@include`

This is how your code could look using scss:

```
@mixin background($color){
  background: $color;
}

@mixin color($color){
  color: $color;
}

.class1 {
  @include background(blue);
}

.class2 {
  @include color(white);
}

.myConsolidatedClass {
  @include background(blue);
  @include color(white);
}
```

Note that you can put any number of properties in the mixins, i just did one for simplicity sake.

Comment: I want something different. sorry was not clear, I need all classes as separate as I use all of them. Yet, in some cases I frequently use the combination. To keep it clean and do not repeat, I am looking to see whether there is a way to set class which would inherit/combine several other classes

Comment: If you want to keep css dry, i would recommend a preprocessor like scss/sass.

However there's nothing wrong with listing out classes in html, check the source on web pages out in the wild, those elements are chock full of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom class to the selectors you want it to share in your CSS file.

```css
.btn, .btn-my {
  color: red;
}
.btn-default, .btn-my {
  padding: 3em;
}
.btn-block, .btn-my {
  display: block;
}
.btn-lg, .btn-my {
  width: 50vw;
}
.mt20, .btn-my {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">btn</button>
<button class="btn-default">btn</button>
<button class="btn-block">btn</button>
<button class="btn-lg">btn</button>
<button class="mt20">btn</button>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg mt20">btn</button>
<button class="btn-my">btn-my</button>
```

Comment: Is there something more simpler like 

.btn-my{.btn .btn-default .btn-block .btn-lg .mt20}

Comment: @ViktorKa nope. You might be able to do that with some sort of CSS pre-processor or site building tool, but not with native CSS.

Comment: @ViktorKa please check out [**Less**](http://lesscss.org/) and [**Sass**](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine those rules into a single new class like this:

```css
.btn-my {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
  .btn-my:hover {
      color: #333;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      border-color: #adadad;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="something" class="btn-my">something</a>
```

Comment: Why would I do that?

Comment: I don't know why _you_ would, this answer is for the OP who asked how to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP isn't looking to copy-n-paste properties from certain classes into a single class.

Comment: The OP asked how they could get the styling from several different classes using a single class. This answer does that. Let's leave it up to the OP to decide.

Comment: In that case, the correct "answer" is to explain to the OP that's there's no reason to do this, unless he wants to end up with brittle, monolithic classes, that no one can remember the names of and you have to edit every time, often in multiple places, every time you turn around.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see link/reference to the answer

Comment: @torazaburo exactly. If `.btn-default` changes then so does `.my-btn`. Manually updating both would be a pain. The only thing that would make this manageable is a CSS preprocessor so any change in `.btn-default` would automatically be updated for `.my-btn`. If I was the OP I'd continue business as usual, using the individual classes.